# how to merge set within set in java?

Tags: java, merge

i want to merge two set element in one.

```
public static <T> Set<Set<Long>> merge(Set<Set<Long>> splitSets, long a, long b) {

    Iterator<Set<Long>> it1 = splitSets.iterator();


    for (long i=0; i<splitSets.size(); i++) {

       HashSet<Long> s1=null,s2 = null,s3 = null;

        for (long j=0; it1.hasNext(); j++) {

            s1=(LinkedHashSet<Long>) it1.next();
            if(s1.contains(a)){
                s2=s1;
            }
            if(s1.contains(b)){
                s3=s1;
            }
        }

        if(s2!=null && s3!=null){
            s2.addAll(s3);
            splitSets.remove(s3);
        }
    }

    return splitSets;
}
```

i have write the above code for merging the inner set element of the outer set. if given value of a and b found in two different set it has to merge into one. it work while there is single element in any of the set but if both set contain more than one element then it merge into first but do not remove the second please help me to find problem.

following are the call of merge method and corresponding output.

original splitSet

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

splitSets = merge(splitSets,3,5);

[[1], [2], **[3, 5]**, [4], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

splitSets = merge(splitSets,2,6);

[[1], **[2, 6]**, **[3, 5]**, [4], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

splitSets = merge(splitSets,6,3);

[[1], **[2, 6, 3, 5]**, ***[3, 5]***, [4], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

Comment: `(LinkedHashSet<Long>) it1.next();` How do you know that each inner `Set` is of type `LinkedHashSet`? The only thing you know for sure is, that is a `Set`, but not which kind of `Set`.

Comment: try to find something about disjoint-set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure, I think this is what you want

Comment: i have implement it for LinkedHashSet all the element are of LinkedHashSet type only. In my main code segment it is LinkedHashSet only.

Comment: @devendrak353 your `merge` doesn't know that and it shouldn't assume that. There is no point in accepting the interface type `Set` if the method tries to cast to a specifc implementation of the `Set` interface. In fact, this dangerous.